# What algorithm does Amazon ELB use to balance load?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-elb

I found this in the official ELB documentation

> By default, a load balancer routes each request independently to the
>   application instance with the smallest load.

but an article on Newvem says that ELB supports only Round Robin algorithm

> **Algorithms supported by Amazon ELB** - Currently Amazon ELB only supports Round Robin (RR) and Session Sticky Algorithms.

So which one is it?

[1] http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/US_StickySessions.html

[2] http://www.newvem.com/dissecting-amazon-elastic-load-balancer-elb-18-facts-you-should-know/?lead_source=popup_ebook&oid=00DD0000000lsYR&email=muneeb%40olacabs.com

Comment: I'd go with the official docs over a year old, unsourced article on a random blog unless given a reason to believe otherwise. Do note, though, that "instance with the smallest load" would apply only to a particular zone - if you have one instance in zone A and two in zone B, the AWS console warns you that requests will be imbalanced.

Comment: 'Do note, though, that "instance with the smallest load" would apply only to a particular zone' < Is it mentioned in the official documentation somewhere?

Comment: I'm sure it's mentioned somewhere, but it's definitely mentioned in the AWS console when you add instances to an ELB. Here's a screenshot: http://cl.ly/image/251m3g1b0E1n

Comment: Abdul, please accept the correct answer, which is crizCraig's.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's request count based for HTTP(S), round robin for other.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/TerminologyandKeyConcepts.html#request-routing

> Before a client sends a request to your load balancer, it first
>   resolves the load balancer's domain name with the Domain Name System
>   (DNS) servers. The DNS server uses DNS round robin to determine which
>   load balancer node in a specific Availability Zone will receive the
>   request.
>
> The selected load balancer node then sends the request to healthy
>   instances within the same Availability Zone. To determine the healthy
>   instances, the load balancer node uses either the round robin (for TCP
>   connections) or the least outstanding request (for HTTP/HTTPS
>   connections) routing algorithm. The least outstanding request routing
>   algorithm favors back-end instances with the fewest connections or
>   outstanding requests.

Comment: This information is slightly out of date. The load-balancer will only send the request to healthy instances within the same availability zone if the cross-zone feature is turned off. The default setting for the cross-zone feature is enabled, thus the load-balancer will send a request to any healthy instance registered to the load-balancer using least-outstanding requests for HTTP/HTTPS, and round-robin for TCP connections.

Comment: Hey @ColtonCat can you please link source for the info

Comment: Reference for info is: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/how-elastic-load-balancing-works.html#routing-algorithm

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the type of ELB used. AWS has over the time introduced Application ELB and Network ELB along with the Classic ELB.

`Application Load Balancers` applies listener rules and assigns the (HTTP/HTTPS) request to a target group. It selects a target from that target group using the `round robin routing algorithm`

`Network Load Balancers` node that receives the connection, selects a target from its target group using a `flow hash routing algorithm`

`Classic Load Balancers` uses `round robin routing algorithm` for TCP listeners and `least outstanding requests routing algorithm` for HTTP and HTTPS listeners

.

TLDR;

> The modern ELBs use `round robin routing algorithm` for HTTP/HTTPS requests
>   and `flow hash routing algorithm` for TCP requests.
>
> Classic ELB used `round robin routing algorithm` for TCP requests and `least outstanding requests routing algorithm` for HTTP and HTTPS requests

Source / Further Reading : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/how-elastic-load-balancing-works.html#routing-algorithm